# Place content, Justify content and align items not working

Tags: html, css

How do I centralize the grid-container?[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsKZ3.png)
I have tried all the answers on other similar problem but it's still not working.
I used justify-content and align-items before changing it to place content.
When I used margin auto, it worked on the horizontal axis.

```css
main {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  place-content: center;
}

.grid-item-1 {
  height: var(--height-grid-item);
  padding: var(--padding-grid-item);
  background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  height: var(--height-grid-item);
  padding: var(--padding-grid-item);
  background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  height: var(--height-grid-item);
  padding: var(--padding-grid-item);
  background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item-1">
    <img src="./sedans.png" alt="sedans">
    <h2>SEDANS</h2>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.
    </p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-2">
    <img src="./suvs.png" alt="suv">
    <h2>SUVS</h2>
    <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.
    </p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-3">
    <img src="./luxury.png" alt="luxury">
    <h2>LUXURY</h2>
    <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style.
    </p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAQOV.png)

Comment: Please clearly state the effect you want and the problems you encounter.

Comment: your question is not clear, how do you wants it to look at the end?

Comment: Hello,  I am trying to centralize the grid container, I used Justify-content and align-items but they did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Vertically centered :**

Your grid-container didn't have a height occupying the whole screen (you can add  `height: 100vh` for this element) , that's why the property `place-content: center` didn't work correctly.

**Horizontally centered :**

You can just add `margin: auto` to your grid container

```css
main{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  place-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh
}

.grid-item-1 {
  height: var(--height-grid-item);
  padding: var(--padding-grid-item);
  background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  height: var(--height-grid-item);
  padding: var(--padding-grid-item);
  background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  height: var(--height-grid-item);
  padding: var(--padding-grid-item);
  background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item-1">
    <img src="./sedans.png" alt="sedans">
    <h2>SEDANS</h2>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.
    </p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-2">
    <img src="./suvs.png" alt="suv">
    <h2>SUVS</h2>
    <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.
    </p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item-3">
    <img src="./luxury.png" alt="luxury">
    <h2>LUXURY</h2>
    <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style.
    </p>
    <button>Learn More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```